# How to get current identity number of specific table in sql server compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I want to get current identity value of a specific table
Like IDENT_CURRENT('table') in sql server

Comment: I know I'll regret asking, but could you explain why?

Comment: As soon as you know the answer, it may be out of date. How would you plan to use it?

Comment: I am converting a program database to sqlce. that program use this command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT AUTOINC_SEED 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableName' 
AND COLUMN_NAME='ColumnName'
```

from [Hamid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17544448/161250) is fine if what you're looking for is what the identity column's seed value is (i.e. what the first ever value of the identity column was or is going to be), but if you're looking for what the next value of an inserted row is going to be, this is the query you want to use:

```
SELECT AUTOINC_NEXT 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableName' 
AND COLUMN_NAME='ColumnName'
```

Answer (score 34):

If you want to get a last identity inserted value for a particular table use the following statement:

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')
```

For example:

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('Employee')
```

Answer (score 9):

```sql
SELECT IDENT_SEED(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME) AS Seed,
IDENT_INCR(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME) AS Increment,
IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME) AS Current_Identity,
TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: Thanks, that one works!
PS: a little typo: just forgotten quote at the end

Answer (score 6):

To check the identity:

```
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[schema].[YourTableName]', NORESEED);
```

To reseed the identity:

```
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[schema].[YourTableName]', RESEED, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it just after an INSERT, you can use

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Otherwise you must use:

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table` won't be any good if you do operations that can wipe the whole table or delete the rows that are currently the `MAX(Id)` value.

Comment: Option-1 works good after insert operation. Option-2 not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tableName or ViewName')
```

Ex:

```sql
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Student')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AUTOINC_SEED 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='tablename' 
and COLUMN_NAME='columnName'
```

Comment: How is this the answer?! This is whatever the identity value was when the table was created, not what its current value is.

Comment: @Alex if you fell that the answer is not correct, feel free to add your own, but do not change other's answers.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Fine, but correcting an answer is not "intended to address the author". You can say that my edit wasn't appropriate, but that rejection reason does not make sense. I wasn't intending to address the author at all.

Comment: It shows the seed value and the not current increment value. Of course, mostly shows the value =1

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @v_identity
SELECT @v_identity = ISNULL(MAX([index]), 0) + 1
FROM [dbo].[Table]
SELECT @v_identity
```