# Avoid arithmetic overflow error when using dbplyr

Tags: r, dbplyr

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271623/dbplyr-error-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-int), but in a summarise so the posted answer doesn't quite fit. The data are such that a row identifies a unit-time pair:

```
large_sql_df
id   t   var1   var2
1    1    10     0
1    2    20     1
2    1    11     0
```

And I would like to aggregate by `var2` and time `t`:

```
localdf <- large_sql_df %>%
     group_by(var, t) %>%
     summarise(count = n(), var1_mean = mean(var1))
```

This gives the error: "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int." I think this is because `count` becomes a very large number. Is there a way to stop this from happening without having to do the entire query in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arithmetic overflow limit is 2,147,483,647 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38700566/7742981)) so this is probably not caused by count. It is much more likely caused by `mean(var1)` because to calculate the mean the computer first has to calculate `sum(var1)`. If your var1 column often contains values greater than 40 then an overflow error is likely (40 * 350 million > 2,147,483,647).

The solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62313491/7742981) is relevant for your question too: Explicitly transform var1 into a more suitable format. Something like the following:

```r
localdf <- large_sql_df %>%
     mutate(var1 = CAST(var1 AS FLOAT)) %>% 
     group_by(var, t) %>%
     summarise(count = n(), var1_mean = mean(var1))
```

Depending on your version of dbplyr you might need something like `mutate(var1 = sql("CAST(var1 AS FLOAT)"))`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server) question for a discussion of different data types. While float is an inexact data type it can handle numbers up to 10E38. If you are taking the average over such a large total then the impression introduced is unlikely to be significant.

Answer (score 2):

This just elaborates some elements of the answer from @simon-s-a:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id   t   var1   var2
1    1    10     0
1    2    20     1
2    1    11     0")

large_sql_df <- dbplyr::tbl_memdb(df)

localdf <- 
  large_sql_df %>%
  mutate(var1 = as.double(var1)) %>% 
  group_by(var2, t) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), var1_mean = mean(var1, na.rm = TRUE),
            .groups = "drop")

localdf
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.35.5 [:memory:]
#>    var2     t count var1_mean
#>   <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
#> 1     0     1     2      10.5
#> 2     1     2     1      20

localdf %>% show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT `var2`, `t`, COUNT(*) AS `count`, AVG(`var1`) AS `var1_mean`
#> FROM (SELECT `id`, `t`, CAST(`var1` AS REAL) AS `var1`, `var2`
#> FROM `df`)
#> GROUP BY `var2`, `t`
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>